# Can't update playonlinux to 4.2.12 version?

Tags: 16.04, updates, playonlinux

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS. I recently installed PlayOnLinux version 4.2.10 but then it reported that PoL has a newer version 4.2.12.

So I went to the  PoL's page and then downloaded the file `PlayOnLinux_4.2.12.deb`. But the version only upgraded to 4.2.11. When I login in PoL,it keep reporting that PoL has version 4.2.12.

I tried to update on terminal but nothing happened then I checked PoL version. It said `PlayOnLinux is already the newest version (4.2.11).`. But when I login PoL,it keeps telling me that I need newer version 4.2.12. How can I fix it?

Comment: Please try to install your `.deb` file using `sudo apt install /path/to/PlayOnLinux_4.2.12.deb`. I just tried it myself in Lubuntu 16.04 and was successfull. If it nevertheless fails on your machine, add the terminal output to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the `.deb` file using the following command:

```
sudo apt install ~/downloads/PlayOnLinux_4.2.12.deb
```

You may need to adjust the path to the directory where you downloaded the file to. Alternatively you can use `gdebi`.

After installing it this way you can check the version

- in the GUI via *Help* → *About PlayOnLinux*
- with `playonlinux --version`:

  ```
  PlayOnLinux 4.2.12
  ```
- with `apt search playonlinux`:

  ```
  playonlinux/now 4.2.12 all [installed,local]
  ```